# Meteor Load Javascript Function After DOM is Loaded

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, mongodb, meteor

I am using Bootstrap in which I have an input checkbox like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle" name="toggle">
```

And I'm using [Bootstrap Switch](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/) to convert it into a switch using their function:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    $("[name='toggle']").bootstrapSwitch();
});
```

However, the problem is that the switch only loads in half the time. I think this is because the function is being called before the checkbox is loaded in the DOM. I thought putting this into the Meteor startup function would fix it but it doesn't. How can I ensure this switch is loaded after the checkbox is loaded?

I've tried `Template.body.onRendered` and it didn't work either.

Comment: Try using `Template.body.onCreated`

Comment: @jswny You want to use `Template.X.onRendered` where `X` is the immediate parent template for the checkbox. This should work in all cases unless the element is conditionally rendered (in which case more tricks are necessary and I'll point you to a related question).

Comment: @chackerian and David Weldon I've tried both of these things and neither worked.

Answer (score 1):

Consider, the above mention code is in template `myTemplate`

**my_template.html**

```
<template name="myTemplate">
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" name="toggle"/>
</template>
```

then your `my_template.js` will have

**my_template.js**

```
if(Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function() {
        $("[name='toggle']").bootstrapSwitch();
    });
}
```